Laravel Vue3 problem to load resources on iPhone with vite
I have encountered the following problem: I created a Ubuntu server to host my Laravel project. The issue is that while every resource loads perfectly on my PC browser, they do not load on my smartphone browser. After debugging, I found that the resources app.ts and app.css couldn't be loaded. After running npm run build for my project, if I change the href to build/assets and then to the hashname, everything works fine except that Tailwind doesn't load correctly, as shown below:
welcome.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/assets/app.CKCEwP1Q.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/assets/app.CKCEwP1Q.css">
</head>
<body class="bg-background cursor-pointer">
    <div id="header"></div>
    {{-- <div id="app">
        <days-grid></days-grid>
    </div> --}}

    <script type="module" src="/build/assets/app.DPd48att.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

When using Vite, everything loads fine on my PC browser, but not on my iPhone browsers (Safari and Chrome):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.ts'])
</head>
<body class="bg-background cursor-pointer">
    <div id="header"></div>
    {{-- <div id="app">
        <days-grid></days-grid>
    </div> --}}
</body>
</html>


Here is my vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import i18n from 'laravel-vue-i18n/vite';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 5173,
        cors: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.ts',
                'resources/css/app.css'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        i18n(),
    ],
    base: '/build/',
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/build',
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash][extname]',
                chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
                entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
            },
        },
    },
    esbuild: {
        target: 'esnext',
        supported: {
            'top-level-await': true
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/js',
        },
    },
});

And my /resources/css/app.css:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

And my /resources/js/app.ts:
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import router from './router/index'
import store from './store'
import Header from './HeaderRoot.vue';
import { i18nVue } from 'laravel-vue-i18n'
import AlertsComponent from './components/AlertsComponent.vue';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
import '../css/ckedotor-reset.css';
import '../css/app.css';
import VueCookies from 'vue3-cookies'
/**
 * @description This is the main entry point for the application. It will create the app and mount the app to the header element.
 * @method createApp
 * @param Header The Header component to be mounted to the header element
 * @param router The router to be used for the app
 */
const app = createApp(Header);
app.component('alerts-component', AlertsComponent);

app.use(router)
app.use(store);
app.use(CKEditor);
app.use(VueCookies);
app.use(i18nVue, {
    resolve: async (lang: any) => {
        const langs = import.meta.glob('../../lang/*.json');
        return await langs[`../../lang/${lang}.json`]();
    }
})

app.mount('#header');

                                                                                /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf                                                                                                 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
    ServerName ##########

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/project>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


   <Directory /var/www/project/resources/js/assets>
        Require all granted
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/public/build>
        Require all granted
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    ProxyPass /vite http://127.0.0.1:5173/
    ProxyPassReverse /vite http://127.0.0.1:5173/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Could anyone help me resolve this issue so that my project loads correctly on both PC and smartphone browsers?
Thank you!
I connected my iPhone to my Mac to debug the browser in Safari, and I retrieved the following headers:


